# copy & paste isolation with win32com & python

Tags: python, excel

Is there a way of using python and win32com to copy and paste such that python scripts can run in the background and not mess up the "users" copy and paste ability?

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import win32com.client

xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename_xls)
ws = xlWb.Worksheets(1)
xlApp.Visible=False

ws.Range('a1:k%s' % row).select
ws.Range('a1:k%s' % row).cut
ws.Range('a7').select
ws.paste
```

assume that the script will be running continuously on a large collection of datasets...

Ok, some more clarity to the question, I need the formating, all of it, so just grabbing t values is of course simple, but not exactly what is needed.

So then let me phrase the question as:
What is there a why to grab both the value and its excel formating in python without the select, copy, and paste routine?

Comment: Can't you just directly access the data and move it from one cell to another, instead of using copy and paste?

Comment: Actually, the reason I would like to cut and paste is to catch all of the formating properties of the cells, I am replicating a bunch of files that have formating that would take a bunch of time to code the formats. So alternatively, how would you copy all the values and formating without copying.

Comment: I don't know the details of the Excel model but I'll bet that formatting information is exposed.  You might want to take a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of:

```
ws.Range('a1:k%s' % row).select
ws.Range('a1:k%s' % row).cut
ws.Range('a7').select
ws.paste
```

I did:

```
ws.Range("A1:K5").Copy(ws.Range("A7:K11"))
```

according to [MSDN: Excel Object Model Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178833%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: I realize this is from 6 years ago - but this is the only solution I can find that will actually paste.

Answer (score 1):

Just read the data out into python, and then write it back.

Instead of:

```
ws.Range('a1:k%s' % row).select
ws.Range('a1:k%s' % row).cut
ws.Range('a7').select
ws.paste
```

Process the data cell-by-cell:

```
for r in range(1, row+1):    # I think Excel COM indexes from 1
    for c in range (1, 12):  # a--k
        val = ws.Cells(r, c).Value
        ws.Cells(r, c).Value = ''    # Blank this cell; equivalent to cut
        ws.Cells(?, ?).Value = val   # Write it somewhere ..
```

I'm not sure what pasting a two-dimensional selection into a single cell does, so I can't do the last line for you.  You may find that you need to do two loops; one to read in the data, and then a second to write it back out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer John, this of course works for values, which is simple... I have clarified the question above, ie. How to get all the formating as well.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but I think I have your solution,
and since I had trouble finding it it'll help someone anyway.
This piece of code will copy everything (value, formula, formating, etc) without
using selections (thus not messing with your users, and this is faster than using selections)

First I open excel like that :

```
xl = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("c:/somepath/file.xls")
xl.Visible = 1
```

To copy and paste on the same worksheet while conserving formating, formulas, etc:

```
ws = wb.Sheets("someSheet") #you can put the sheet number instead of it's name
ws.Range('a1:k%s' % row).Copy() #copy works on all range objects (ws.Columns(), ws.Cells, etc)
ws.Paste(ws.Range('a7'))
```

To copy and paste on an other worksheet while conserving formating, formulas, etc:

```
source_ws = wb.Sheets("SheetContainingData")
destination_ws = wb.Sheets("SheetWhereItNeedsToGo")
source_ws.Range('a1:k%s' % row).Copy()
destination_ws.Paste(destination_ws.Range('a7'))
```

**case sensitive.**