# Python + Win32: Paste header from one Excel workbook to the top of another

Tags: python, excel, winapi, pywin32, win32com

I want to format an Excel report automatically. I generate the raw data using Python for reports, but they need pretty formatting (colors, bold font, borders) on them before they go to a Project Manager.

My current approach is using the `pywin32` package, copying the header from a Template file, and pasting it into my Output report.

I am having trouble with the `.Paste()` methods, for instance, if I try to specify the destination with `.Paste(Destination=Range('A1:A100')` it will throw an error. If I attempt `output_worksheet.used_range.Paste()` it will not recognize `used_range` as valid either.

Additionally my current code doesn't exit out of Excel.

Finally my code pastes the header into row 16 instead of starting from the top:

```py
template_path = tests.path + r"\Box Tracking Report Regents Template.xlsx"
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y %I%M%p")
output_path = tests.path + r"\Box Tracking Report " + timestamp + ".xlsx"

# (... write my pandas dataframe in ...) 

def paste_formatting(tab_name):
    excel_instance = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
    template = excel_instance.Workbooks.Open(template_path)
    template_workbook = excel_instance.Workbooks.Item(1)
    template_worksheet = template_workbook.Worksheets(tab_name)
    used_range = template_worksheet.UsedRange
    used_range.Copy()
    output_excel = excel_instance.Workbooks.Open(output_path)
    output_workbook = excel_instance.Workbooks.Item(2)
    output_worksheet=output_workbook.Worksheets(tab_name)
    output_worksheet.Paste()
    output_workbook.Close()
    template_workbook.Close()

paste_formatting('Regents Box Tracking Report')
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you just put the first cell in Destination=Range('A1')?

Comment: `output_worksheet.Paste(Destination=output_worksheet.Range("A1"))` doesn't work, nor does `output_worksheet.Paste(Destination="A1")`, nor `output_worksheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial()` :'(

Comment: Duplicate of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530682/copy-paste-isolation-with-win32com-python

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't see that - it helped give my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With @chucklukowski's comment:

```py
def paste_formatting(tab_name):
    excel_instance = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
    template = excel_instance.Workbooks.Open(template_path)
    template_workbook = excel_instance.Workbooks.Item(1)
    template_worksheet = template_workbook.Worksheets(tab_name)
    used_range = template_worksheet.UsedRange
    used_range.Copy()
    output_excel = excel_instance.Workbooks.Open(output_path)
    output_workbook = excel_instance.Workbooks.Item(2)
    output_worksheet=output_workbook.Worksheets(tab_name)
    output_worksheet.Paste(output_worksheet.Range('A1'))
    output_workbook.Save()
    output_workbook.Close()
    template_workbook.Close()
    excel_instance.Quit()
    del excel_instance

paste_formatting('Regents Box Tracking Report')
```

Still messy, but probably better than calling an Excel VBA macro from the template itself (which was going to be my last ditch approach).