# Copy and paste image from a ppt file to another ppt file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerpoint

I am using the below code to copy an image from one ppt to another ppt.but it is not working

```
ppt = win32com.client.Dispatch('Powerpoint.Application')
ppt1 = ppt.Presentations.Open("path\\temp.pptx")
ppt2 = ppt.Presentations.Open("path\\2paste.pptx")
ppt1.slide.Shapes.Copy()
ppt2.slide.Shapes.Paste()
```

This code opens both the ppt but it is not copying the images.

Comment: Ref this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530682/copy-paste-isolation-with-win32com-python

Comment: Thanks Reegan, But this example shows from excel to ppt no?

Answer (score 1):

With [Aspose.Slides for Python](https://products.aspose.com/slides/python-net/), you can easily copy any shapes from a presentation to another. The following code example shows you how to do this:

```py
import aspose.slides as slides

file_name1 = "temp.pptx"
file_name2 = "2paste.pptx"

with slides.Presentation(file_name1) as presentation1:
    with slides.Presentation(file_name2) as presentation2:

        # Get the first shape from the first slide, for example.
        first_shape = presentation1.slides[0].shapes[0]

        # Clone the shape and add the clone to the second presentation.
        presentation2.slides[0].shapes.add_clone(first_shape)

        # Save the second presentation.
        presentation2.save(file_name2, slides.export.SaveFormat.PPTX)
```

This is a paid library, but you can get a temporary licence for evaluating all features for your purposes. I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.